# Nextcloud in Docker & MySQL on Host

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, nextcloud

I'm running docker on my Raspberry Pi. I'm intending to run a few services locally (NextCloud, Bitwarden, etc) and want to use one MariaDB Instance, not one for each as most tutorial show. I've been trying to figure out how to make that work.

I installed mariadb on my RPI and nextcloud via Docker. I passed the MySQL environment variables to that container:

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
  - MYSQL_USER=user
  - MYSQL_HOST=192.168.178.36
```

When I go to the NC initialization page and enter the data, it says Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused".

I addded "user@IP" to MySQL and granted it all access to the DB. The IP is the Docker-internal IP of the Container (172.xxx)

Comment: sounds like the port isn't exposed from the container.

Comment: To add to this, default port for MySQL is 3306

Comment: So I need to expose port 3306 to my NC container? I can't do 3306:3306 because MySQL is using it already. Do I need to do randomport:3306 then?

Comment: @FlyingPersian Are you using docker-compose (the `environment` bit you posted makes me think yes)? If so please post the entire docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: This can actually be closed! I tried mariadb in a docker environment again and put all my containers in the same network and now it works

Comment: The mistake *might* be, that the containers network could not reach `192.168.178.36`. It might be more like `172.17.0.1` -- But **for sure** your approach is much better suited for containerization ;)